# How can I train my cat to resume outside toileting?

Tags: cats, toilet-training

I have a 5yr old cat that has never had toileting issues, no litter boxes ever required as she has always gone to the toilet outside.

We have had to unfortunately put our dear old dog down (whom she got along with) & ever since then we are finding pee on the lounge suite etc. I think it is be a territorial problem as our recluse cat has started coming out to the lounge which she has never done.

How do I stop her from peeing indoors? I would like for her to resume toileting outdoors.

Comment: First step is to give her a litterbox so she has a better alternative. Second step is vet; toileting changes often indicate a medical problem.

Comment: @keshlam That sounds like a complete, if brief, answer to me.

Answer (score 2):

When my cat was a kitten, she had a litter box. Due to bad communications between us who lived there, the box did not get cleaned as often as it should, so the cat started doing her business only outside. We kept the box around for some time, but she never used it again, and we trashed it.

Some years later, the cat disappeared. She was found six weeks later 20 km from home, and returned to me, thanks to her chip. After this incident, she was afraid to go outside. She would go out if I accompanied her, but was reluctant to go alone. Naturally, the cat still had to do her business, so carpets, blankets and corners became targets for her needs.

We bought her a new litter box, and gave her time. She gradually started to go more and more outside alone, but actually came in to use the litter box when she had to go, then jumped out again. Now, a year later, she is back to her normal self, and hasn't used the box in months.

So my suggestion is to get a litter box, and teach your cat to use it. DO NOT shame your cat for going on your furniture if it has no alternative. See Sienna Vaile's answer. Then just give it time. Maybe it will fall back into its old habits, maybe it won't.

Answer (score 2):

I would try a couple of things. First off, provide a litter box. Like puppy pads, this just channels where they go. Also, start confining her to one room. If you think it's territorial, reduce the amount of territory. She might not feel the need to mark it if she's there all the time.

If all that works, then try moving the litter box outside and/or letting her out to go to the bathroom more frequently. Hopefully, she'll progress to going strictly outside, but it's also possible that you'll always need a litter box. That switch flips in their heads and sometimes they just change. You've got to roll with it unless you want all your stuff peed on. Hopefully, this helps, though.

Answer (score 0):

Is your cat a barn cat or a indoor/house cat? If it went to the bathroom outside, then it would have been a barn cat. If he's just a regular indoor/house cat, I would suggest purchasing a litter box, so that it wouldn't pee in the house all the time. If it's still peeing in the house, try putting the cat in the litter box ever 15-20 minutes. If you are just introducing your cat to the litter box, rub your fingers in the sand to show the cat that the litter box is her territory. Once it is in the litter box, let the cat get used to the smells and feels of the litter. If the cat jumps out, put it back in again. If the cat still doesn't pee, and jumps out after the second try, the cat just probably doesn't have to go. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think they're a barn cat because they go to the bathroom outside. I think a barn cat is almost feral and mostly live off what they kill. My cat is mostly indoors, but never uses a litter box. He asks to go outside and uses one of several trees.